# How to draw lines parallel to the width of minimum area rectangle joing opposite contour points using OpenCV python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to draw lines parallel to the width of minimum area rectangle drawn on a contour which connect the opposite points of the contour. What I intend to do with this is to find the real width of the contour.
To find the real width of the objects, I currently use a reference object inside the images and to find pixel per cm value which is used to convert the width value obtained in pixel to cm.To find the width I am using Minimum Area Rectangle method present in OpenCV, I have also tried finding the leftmost and rightmost contour points and then joining them to find there length but the values are always over predicted.
Following is the code that I am using to find the values.

```
commodity_mask = copy.deepcopy(r['masks'][i]).astype(np.uint8)
im, contours_m, hierarchy  = cv2.findContours(commodity_mask, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = max(contours_m, key=cv2.contourArea)leftmost = tuple(contours[contours[:,:,0].argmin()][0])
rightmost = tuple(contours[contours[:,:,0].argmax()][0])
topmost = tuple(contours[contours[:,:,1].argmin()][0])
bottommost = tuple(contours[contours[:,:,1].argmax()][0])
cv2.circle(minrect, leftmost, 8, (0, 50, 255), -1)
cv2.circle(minrect, rightmost, 8, (0, 50, 255), -1)
cv2.line(minrect, leftmost, rightmost, (0,0,255),2)
dist = np.sqrt((leftmost[0]-rightmost[0])**2 + (leftmost[1]-rightmost[1])**2)
dist = dist*ratio     #finding distance b/w leftmost and rightmost contour point and converting them to pixels.

commodity_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(commodity_contour)  # (top-left corner(x,y), (width, height), angle of rotation)
cv2.drawContours(minrect, [np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(commodity_rect))], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
(xrect, yrect), (wrect, hrect), alpha = commodity_rect
print('Width: ', wrect * ratio, 'Height: ', hrect * ratio)
```

The  `r['masks'][i]` value is the ith contour obtained in from the image.

So far I have achieved is the following image.

[image: contours]

The green boxes are the minimum area rectangle drawn on the contour and the red line joins the leftmost and rightmost points of the contour.

What I want to do is the following.

[image]

Draw lines parallel to the width of the rectangle(yellow ones) which join the opposite points of the contour, then I can find their lengths and use them to find the width of the contour.

This is the original image, without the rectangles drawn.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to construct and measure the yellow lines in the final image, yes? Why aren't there any yellow lines on peppers #2 and #3 ?

Comment: Can you share the original Image?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have drwan the yellow lines just to illustrate that I want to draw those lines, that's why I have drawn it only on some peppers and not all. I want some way in whcih I can draw those.

Comment: @VatsalParsaniya that's the original image. Do you mean without the rectangle and lines?

Comment: Yes, without the rectangle and lines.

Comment: Ok, so what do we do with peppers #2 and #3 please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, we do nothing with those peppers. In other words what I want is a method to draw those yellow lines on all those peppers.

Comment: @VatsalParsaniya added the original image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you to find your desired line coordinates. I have used the `cv2.pointPolygonTest` on contours point to find your desired points. more about `cv2.pointPolygonTest` [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html#point-polygon-test)

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('image.png')

image = cv2.resize(image, (800, 800))
output_image = image.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

HSV = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
low = np.array([33, 91, 21])
high = np.array([253, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(HSV, low, high)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_contour = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)

# As I know there is 6 max contour we want I'm selecting 6 contour only to creating perfact mask
selected_contour = sorted_contour[:6]
blank_mask = np.zeros_like(mask)
mask = cv2.drawContours(blank_mask, selected_contour, -1, 255, -1)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)

for i, cnt in enumerate(selected_contour):
    # find min enclosing rect
    commodity_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    cv2.drawContours(output_image, [np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(commodity_rect))], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # find center point of rect
    M = cv2.moments(cnt)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    cv2.circle(output_image, (cX, cY), 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)

    selceted_points = [[px, cY] for [[px, py]] in cnt if cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt, (px, cY), measureDist=False) == 0]

    left_point = min(selceted_points, key=lambda x: x[0])
    right_point = max(selceted_points, key=lambda x: x[0])

    print(f"\nfor {i}th contour : ")
    print("left_point : ", left_point)
    print("right_point : ", right_point)

    cv2.circle(output_image, tuple(left_point), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(output_image, tuple(right_point), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.line(output_image, tuple(left_point), tuple(right_point), (0, 0, 255), 1)

cv2.imshow("output_image", output_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

```
for 0th contour : 
left_point :  [606, 613]
right_point :  [786, 613]

for 1th contour : 
left_point :  [73, 233]
right_point :  [211, 233]

for 2th contour : 
left_point :  [329, 248]
right_point :  [501, 248]

for 3th contour : 
left_point :  [58, 637]
right_point :  [246, 637]

for 4th contour : 
left_point :  [364, 600]
right_point :  [508, 600]

for 5th contour : 
left_point :  [605, 237]
right_point :  [753, 237]
```

Mask Image:
[image]

Output Image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In solution one, I misunderstood something and find a horizontal line on the bounding box,
this is your desired line cordinates.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


def get_order_points(pts):
    # first - top-left,
    # second - top-right
    # third - bottom-right
    # fourth - bottom-left

    rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype="int")

    # top-left point will have the smallest sum
    # bottom-right point will have the largest sum
    s = pts.sum(axis=1)
    rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
    rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]

    # top-right point will have the smallest difference
    # bottom-left will have the largest difference
    diff = np.diff(pts, axis=1)
    rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
    rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]

    return rect


image = cv2.imread('image.png')

image = cv2.resize(image, (800, 800))
output_image = image.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

HSV = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
low = np.array([33, 91, 21])
high = np.array([253, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(HSV, low, high)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_contour = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)

# As I know there is 6 max contour we want I'm selecting 6 contour only to creating perfact mask
selected_contour = sorted_contour[:6]
blank_mask = np.zeros_like(mask)
mask = cv2.drawContours(blank_mask, selected_contour, -1, 255, -1)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imwrite("mask.png", mask)

for i, cnt in enumerate(selected_contour):
    # find min enclosing rect
    commodity_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    bounding_rect_points = np.array(cv2.boxPoints(commodity_rect), dtype=np.int)
    cv2.drawContours(output_image, [bounding_rect_points], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    tl, tr, br, bl = get_order_points(bounding_rect_points)

    left_point = (tl + bl) // 2
    right_point = (tr + br) // 2

    print(f"\nfor {i}th contour : ")
    print("left_point : ", left_point)
    print("right_point : ", right_point)

    cv2.circle(output_image, tuple(left_point), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(output_image, tuple(right_point), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.line(output_image, tuple(left_point), tuple(right_point), (0, 0, 255), 1)

cv2.imshow("output_image", output_image)
cv2.imwrite("output_image.png", output_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

```
for 0th contour : 
left_point :  [606 597]
right_point :  [785 622]

for 1th contour : 
left_point :  [ 64 236]
right_point :  [214 236]

for 2th contour : 
left_point :  [325 201]
right_point :  [507 295]

for 3th contour : 
left_point :  [ 56 638]
right_point :  [244 619]

for 4th contour : 
left_point :  [359 574]
right_point :  [504 625]

for 5th contour : 
left_point :  [605 241]
right_point :  [753 241]
```

Output_Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this:

```
commodity_rect = cv2.minAreaRect(commodity_contour) #Find the minAreaRect for each contour
minAxis = round(min(commodity_rect[1])) #Find minor axis size
maxAxis = round(max(commodity_rect[1])) #Find major axis size
```

but instead of minAreaRect, what I think you're looking for is the rotating caliper algorithm. Take a look at the link below:

[https://chadrick-kwag.net/python-implementation-of-rotating-caliper-algorithm/#:~:text=Rotating%20caliper%20algorithm%20is%20used,all%20possible%20rotating%20caliper%20rectangles](https://chadrick-kwag.net/python-implementation-of-rotating-caliper-algorithm/#:%7E:text=Rotating%20caliper%20algorithm%20is%20used,all%20possible%20rotating%20caliper%20rectangles).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).